# base 64 string to hexa string

Tags: c++, base64

How can i conver from base64 string to hexa string (i'm working in ubuntu - c++ code). My hexa string I would like to be like 0x0c....and so on. Need help. Can someone please give me an exaple?Thx!

Comment: There are at least twelve different ways a base64 encoded string can be converted to a string of hexadecimal numbers, all having a different result – and it’s not obvious which of these results you’re talking about. Please elaborate which kind of conversion you had in mind.

Comment: This takes two conversions.  First from base64 to unsigned char[].  Then from that to a string of hex digits.  Both of which are well covered by other questions under the c++ tag.

Comment: @Hans:  That isn't really accurate.  His base64 string is already a character array; what is needed is to convert it from a character array TO an integer, and then back into a character array with Hex encoding.

Comment: for example I have the string vallue: std::string ssir = "DNQwSinfOUSSWd+U04r23A=="; I would like the create a char values[]={ 0x0C, 0xD4, 0x30, 0x4a, 0x29, 0xdf, 0x39, 0x44, 0x92, 0x59, 0xdf, 0x94, 0xd3, 0x8a, 0xf6, 0xdc }; Which is the hexa of the ssir base64

Comment: Actually, it's not. In memory, it's all binary. That `0x0C`? That's really `00001100`. As Hans Passant said, you really want the Base64 to binary decoding. The binary to hex you usually get for free (for instance, when looking at `char values[]` in the debugger.)

Answer (score -1):

A quick solution that uses common (though not standard) functions:

```
std::string input = MY_ENCODED_STRING;
unsigned long decoded_value = strtol(input.c_str(), NULL, 64);
char buffer[100] = {0};
std::string output = itoa(decoded_value, buffer, 16);
```

`boost::lexical_cast` may be able to provide a more elegant solution (not sure on that one, though).

Comment: i'm working in ubuntu, under c++ code. What is itoa? In whay library to I find it?

Comment: I need a c++ example. Can someone help me pls? Thx

Comment: `itoa` is usually included in `stdlib.h` if your compiler supports it (again, it is not a standard function, but is fairly common).

Comment: The wikipedia article has an example of such a string.  Imagine what happens when you use strtol() on it.

Comment: I have the following error at itoa: error: invalid conversion from ‘long unsigned int’ to ‘const char*’

Comment: @eliza:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/ for reference.  @Hans:  `strtol` handles different bases (hence the base input argument).

Comment: As a side note, on some systems, the implementation of strtol only supports up to base 32.  The `a64l`/`l64a` family can handle the same basic logic if available though.

Comment: I did decode with base64 the string value. What is the command for converting a string to hex?

Comment: The `itoa` call above will work, as will `printf("%X", decoded_value);` (or any of its family members).

Comment: Zac..I'm using c++ under Linux. Isn't there any other solution? WIth itoa is not working...

Comment: Here is the sollution: std::stringstream ss;
for (int i=0; i<dec.size(); ++i) {
    if (i != 0) ss << ':';
   
   ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') <<  cast<unsigned int>(dec[i]);//(int)(dec[i]);
}
std::string res;
res= ss.str();
cout<<"the ress is: "<<res<<std::endl;

Comment: why do i receive ffff values besides the ones i'm expecting for?